# How can i get a NSDate from this string "2010-11-01"

Tags: iphone, nsdate

can any one tell me why i cant get a proper NSDate from this string "2010-11-01"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your date is of the format yyyy-MM-dd:

```
NSDateFormatter *f = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [f dateFromString:@"2010-11-01"];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Comment: For posterity, you should add [f release]; to the end of that.

Comment: You may also want to note that if this style of date is parsed frequently, you'll definitely want to create an NSDateFormatter and simply hold on to it, as initting the date formatter is far more expensive than actually converting a string. If you do this, be warned that NSDateFormatter is not thread-safe.

Comment: @Steven - (Added "autorelease") I just had to be different! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

With `NSDateFormatter`.